# Custom style on profile options page

Tags: users, options, profiles

is there any way to style the profile page on wordpress ? I will like to add something like:

**Start of the page just below the `<h2>` tag**

```
<div id="normal-sortables" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
    <div id="poststuff" class="metabox-holder has-right-sidebar">
        <div id="post-body">
            <div id="post-body-content" style="margin-right: 0 !important;">
                <div id="normal-sortables" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
```

**Before each opening `<table>` tag** (note "the php_e('name')" )

```
<div id="namepage" class="postbox ">
    <h3 style="cursor: default !important;"><?php _e('Name') ?></h3>
        <div class="inside">
```

**After each closing `</table>` tag**

```
    </div>
</div>
```

**After the `</form>` tag**

```
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not interested in adding a custom CSS file, I will be happy to use what is there already.

As a test I edited the user-edit.php from wp-admin and it looks fine, in my opinion much better.

Is there any proper way to add these div's to the page.

Edit, I'm aware of the following code, but I hope some body can help with the "preg_replace" to add the above div's.

```
function users_edited($buffer) {
if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {
        global $pagenow;
        if ($pagenow == 'profile.php' || $pagenow == 'users.php' || $pagenow == 'user-edit.php') {
            //Hide the Name table
            $name = '#<h3>Name</h3>.+?<table.+?/table>#s';
            $buffer=preg_replace($name,'',$buffer,1);
            $personal = array('#<h3>Name</h3>.+?<table.+?/table>#s', '#<h3>Personal Options</h3>.+?<table.+?/table>#s');
            $buffer=preg_replace($personal,'',$buffer,1);

            //Modiffy Contact Person header from h2 to h3
            $contactperson='#<h2>Contact Person</h2>#';
            $buffer=preg_replace($contactperson,'<h3>Contact Person</h3>',$buffer,1);

        }
        return $buffer;
    }
}
function users_edit_start() { 
if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {
        ob_start("users_edited"); 
    }
}
function users_edit_end() { 
if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) {
        ob_end_flush(); 
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'users_edit_start');
add_action('admin_footer', 'users_edit_end');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on a standard profile page (your profile / Profile) without other plugins installed.

Other plugins may affect the overall result. I think code can be improved, if some one knows how please give it a go.[image]

```
function better_profile_page($buffer) {
        global $pagenow;
            if ($pagenow == 'profile.php' || $pagenow == 'users.php' || $pagenow == 'user-edit.php') {
                $form_start = '#<form id="your-profile" action="'.esc_url( self_admin_url( IS_PROFILE_PAGE ? 'profile.php' : 'user-edit.php' ) ).'" method="post">#';
                $new_form_start = '<form id="your-profile" action="'.esc_url( self_admin_url( IS_PROFILE_PAGE ? 'profile.php' : 'user-edit.php' ) ).'" method="post"><div id="normal-sortables" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
                <div id="poststuff" class="metabox-holder has-right-sidebar">
                    <div id="post-body">
                        <div id="post-body-content" style="margin-right: 0 !important;">
                            <div id="normal-sortables" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">';
                $buffer=preg_replace($form_start, $new_form_start ,$buffer,1);

                $h3_open_a = '#<h3>#';
                $buffer=preg_replace($h3_open_a,'<div id="namepage" class="postbox "><h3 style="cursor: default !important;">',$buffer,1);

                $h3_close = '#</h3>#';
                $buffer=preg_replace($h3_close,'</h3><div class="inside">',$buffer,1);

                $h3_open_b = '#<h3>#';
                $buffer=preg_replace($h3_open_b,'</div></div><div id="namepage" class="postbox "><h3 style="cursor: default !important;">',$buffer);

                $submit_button = '#<p class="submit">#';
                $buffer=preg_replace($submit_button,'<p class="submit" style="float: left ! important; padding: 12px ! important;">',$buffer);

                $form_close =  '#</form>#';
                $new_form_close = '</div></div></div></form>';
                $buffer=preg_replace($form_close, $new_form_close ,$buffer,1);
            }
            return $buffer;
    }
    function edit_profile_page_start() { 
            ob_start("better_profile_page"); 
    }
    function edit_profile_page_end() { 
            ob_end_flush(); 
    }
    add_action('admin_head', 'edit_profile_page_start');
    add_action('admin_footer', 'edit_profile_page_end');
```

Answer (score 0):

You've been poking around in the right pages. I think you know the answer already. :) If you see a hook in the right place you can do it. Otherwise, do what you can with CSS, or Javascript, and if that isn't enough you are looking at a core edit. If you saw a hook you probably wouldn't be asking, so...

You also have the option of [opening a ticket and submitting a patch to WordPress](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/) and try to get the hooks you want.

Comment: Well, I think I'm close now, but still I need some help with the "preg_replace" part of that script.

Comment: Ha! That output buffering trick was clever. You should post it as an answer. Which `preg_replace` is causing trouble? That question is more a PHP question that a WordPress one so it may be better suited to stackoverflow proper.

Comment: None/All , I don't know how to start that is the problem. I been loking at this all day, and now that I'm that close my brain goes blank :( I will give it a go later and post a follow up on the problem.